# How to get User Input in Python 3 when input() returns errors

Tags: python, input, printing, traceback

- In python 3 I am getting errors when I use input() and I want to take user input and do something with it.
- I am executing the python script in BBEdit, Sublime or IDLE.
- Code results in errors unless I remove the Input() Syntax:

> input("Hi I'm new to python")

> userInput = input("Enter a string")
> print(f"You entered {userInput}")

In the console it displays the string from input("String") but any user keystrokes are instead typed in the code editor, not interactively.

I read that Python could not be interactive via those apps but I don't understand how to execute a syntactically correct "input("enter your favorite sushi roll") and interact with it  (on pc and Mac)

From Console:

> Enter a string 
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/michaelking/Desktop/BBEditRunTemp-hellowWorld.py", line 1, in 
> userInput = input("Enter a string") 
> EOFError: EOF when reading a line 
> ================================================================================
> Nov 2, 2020 at 9:53:07 PM
> ~/Desktop/hellowWorld.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/michaelking/Desktop/BBEditRunTemp-hellowWorld.py", line 1, in 
> userInput = input()
> EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Your code works just fine for me using python 3.7 in Vscode and pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

```
userInput = input("Enter a string")
print("You entered {}".format(userInput))
```

Comment: sorry but this doesn't execute in BBEdit or Sublime. The string "Enter a string" is printed in console but you cannot interact. Meaning you cannot actually enter data.

Comment: BEGIN CONSOLE TEXT 
Enter a string
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/michaelking/Desktop/BBEditRunTemp-hellowWorld.py", line 1, in <module>
    userInput = input("Enter a string")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Answer (score 0):

When you're running a script that requires interactive input, you'll have to run it in Terminal (or an equivalent such as iTerm).

I can't speak to other products :-) but when using BBEdit, the "Run in Terminal" command on the #! menu will do this for you.